# Attach Event Handler to Node Syntax

Tags: javascript, events, button, onclick

I've attached a 'click' event to a 'button' element (type=submit) so that clicking on the latter element copies data from one field (input type=text) to another.  However, the copy is only temporary and reverts to blank or default values.

Affecting Firefox/Opera/Chrome

Comment: When you say that the copy is only temporary, do you mean that the values are blank/temporary when you check on the server-side?

Comment: Sorry, they are visually blank, resulting from form submit (thanks for pointing that out @JosephSilber).  However, return false on the FORM handler didn't work, and I learned about prevent default!  
`function submitIntercept (e) {  
  alert("form handler");  
  e.preventDefault();  
  return false;  
}  `  
This worked just fine even with type='submit' on the button.  However, I believe with IE I am going to have to set 'returnValue' property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the submit button is clicked, it also submits the form, which causes a page refresh.

You'll have to `return false` from your click event handler:

```
$('#theSubmitButton').click(function(){
    // code to copy values goes here
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I thought it might be related to the type=submit, but the whole "it's called Button ALREADY, come ON!" made me impatient with the redundant aspect of the whole issue.  I'm not using jQuery, and I added 'return false' to no avail.  Googling results in alot of 'inline code' examples with return false, not the addEventListener/attachEvent approach I'm using.  I learned that this is called Advanced Reg Model:  I thought it was just the right way to do things.  I figured it out though, and am posting the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the button input to type="button" instead of type="submit" if the button doesn't need to submit anything to the server (which by the looks of your question, it doesn't).

type="submit" will run the form's action/postback and cause a refresh.

Comment: He might want it so that if javascript is disabled, the form still submits.

Comment: Judging purely by his question and tags used, it looks as if he just wants the button to copy text from one textbox to another.

Comment: I wanted just to copy text, but I also wanted to use a submit type for my own nefarious reasons, while using button for greater formatting flexibility and easier styling in my css.